Unable to create a userrole in Apex for a community user
Unable to create a userrole in Apex for a community user.
When a community user is manually assigned to an account, three userroles are generated with the portaltype CustomerPortal;
however, when we try to create the same via Apex, we receive an error.
Line: 9, Column: 1

System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; 
first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Cannot specify system-maintained portal role field: [Name]
Unable to create a userrole in Apex for a community user. 
When a community user is manually assigned to an account, three userroles are generated with the portaltype CustomerPortal; 
however, when we try to create the same via Apex, we receive an error.

Line: 9, Column: 1

System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; 
first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Cannot specify system-maintained portal role field: [Name]

Code:
UserRole ure = new UserRole(

name = 'TEST BANK  Customer Executive',

parentRoleId = '00E1W000001XXXXX',

PortalType = 'CustomerPortal',

PortalAccountId ='001Ea00000FvXXXXX'

);

insert ure;

 

UserRole urm = new UserRole(

name = 'TEST BANK  Customer Manager',

    parentRoleId = ure.Id,

    PortalType = 'CustomerPortal',

    PortalAccountId ='001Ea00000FvXXXXX'

);

insert urm;

 

UserRole urc = new UserRole(

name = 'TEST BANK Customer User',

    parentRoleId = urm.Id,

    PortalType = 'CustomerPortal',

    PortalAccountId ='001Ea00000FXXXXXX'

);

insert urc;

 

#Salesforce Developer  #Experience Cloud  #B2B Commerce  #Commerce Cloud  #UserRole Object

